# How do I control the axis labels on a ggvis plot where the variables to be plotted are selected interactively?

Tags: r, ggvis

I am trying to create an interactive visualization with the ggvis package.

Specifically, the user should be able to select which of the variables should be plotted on which axes. One way to do this was already presented in answer 2 of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840804/is-it-possible-with-ggvis-to-interactively-change-the-variables-for-the-x-and-y). However in this solution the axes are not labeled correctly:

E.g. in this example

```
library("ggvis")
library("magrittr")
sel <- input_select(names(mtcars),map=as.name)
mtcars %>% ggvis(sel,~mpg) %>% layer_points()
```

The y-axis has a label of "reactive_x" (x being a random number).
I would now like to label the y-axis according to the currently selected variable. Adding

```
%>% add_axis("y",title=sel)
```

does not work because sel is a closure, not a character vector. Wrapping sel in as.character does not work either.

Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

Note: This would possibly easier to solve by wrapping the ggvis plot in a shiny app. However, I am not interested in such solutions as this visualization will be part of a package that I am developing.

Comment: Hmm, might not be possible according to [this github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/203).  Maybe just remove the label on the x-axis and add a title like "Choose variable for x axis" to the dropdown menu?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, this is my current solution, although I think showing the name would be a little nicer. I still have hope that this might be possible in some way that I have overlooked, because this issue is about legends and not axis labels.