# How to pass variable name as axis label in interactive ggvis?

Tags: r, ggvis

This code generates the chart I want, but I would like to pass the content of `input_radiobuttons` as vertical axis label in place of the random string `reactive_931110099`.

[image]

```
library(ggvis)
mtcars %>% ggvis(x = ~wt, y= input_radiobuttons( 
     choices = c("mpg" = 'mpg', "disp" = 'disp'),
      label = "Y-axis",
      map = as.name)
     )
    layer_densities(
      adjust = input_slider(.1, 2, value = 1, step = .1, label = "Bandwidth adjustment"),
      kernel = input_select(
        c("Gaussian" = "gaussian",
          "Epanechnikov" = "epanechnikov",
          "Rectangular" = "rectangular",
          "Triangular" = "triangular",
          "Biweight" = "biweight",
          "Cosine" = "cosine",
          "Optcosine" = "optcosine"),
        label = "Kernel")
    )
```

Comment: Does not seem possible at this point -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464822/how-do-i-control-the-axis-labels-on-a-ggvis-plot-where-the-variables-to-be-plott

Answer (score 1):

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(x = ~wt, y= input_radiobuttons( 
     choices = c("mpg" = 'mpg', "disp" = 'disp'),
      label = "Y-axis",
      map = as.name)
     ) %>%
   add_axis("y", title = "Pick Your Own Label", title_offset = 50)
    layer_densities(
      adjust = input_slider(.1, 2, value = 1, step = .1, label = "Bandwidth adjustment"),
      kernel = input_select(
        c("Gaussian" = "gaussian",
          "Epanechnikov" = "epanechnikov",
          "Rectangular" = "rectangular",
          "Triangular" = "triangular",
          "Biweight" = "biweight",
          "Cosine" = "cosine",
          "Optcosine" = "optcosine"),
        label = "Kernel")
    )
```

[image]