# ggvis - using a variable to assign "x" property using props

Tags: r, ggvis

According to the [properties and scales reference](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/properties-scales.html) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25750479/6668632) I should be able to use a props(prop()) call as shown below to create the graph. I'm getting an unintelligible error though.

```
test_df <- data.frame(cbind(x_vals = letters[1:5],
                            y_vals = 1:5))
```

**Graphs correctly:**

```
test_df %>% ggvis(x = ~x_vals, y = ~y_vals) %>% 
  layer_points()
```

**Has error:**

```
x_val_variable <- "x_vals"

test_df %>% ggvis(y = ~y_vals) %>% 
      props(prop("x", as.name(x_val_variable)) %>% 
      layer_points()
```

Can anyone help me by telling me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That `props()` stuff does seem confusing. I'm pretty sure you can't have in in the `%>%` chain. It should either be in the `ggvis()~ or `layer_points()` call. I couldn't get it to work but I did get `test_df %>% ggvis(x=as.name(x_val_variable), y = ~y_vals) %>% layer_points()` to work. which seems to do what you want.

Comment: I figured it out. You are correct that `props()` doesn't belong in the chain. I spent a good 5 hours on this today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the correct usage of `prop()`, it doesn't belong in the `%>%` chain, it's an argument of `ggvis` or `layer_points()`. I still don't understand when you would use `props()` though.

```
test_df <- data.frame(cbind(x_vals = letters[1:5],
                            y_vals = 1:5)) 

x_val_variable <- "x_vals"

#you can use either one of these, they are identical
p1 <- prop("x", as.name(x_val_variable))
p2 <- prop("x", parse(text = x_val_variable)[[1]])

test_df %>% ggvis(p1, y = ~y_vals) %>% layer_points()
```