# R ggvis:use input_select to set variable on x-axis

Tags: r, ggvis

I am trying to set the x variable in a ggvis plot using input_select. Suppose the following base plot:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
  layer_points()
```

I read [here](https://ggvis.rstudio.com/interactivity.html) that I should use this expression:

```
prop(x = input_select(c("disp", "wt")), constant = FALSE)
```

But I don't know how to combine these two pieces of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it !!!

```
xVariables = c("hp","disp")

mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(prop("x", input_select(xVariables, map=as.name), scale = TRUE), y=~mpg) %>%
  scale_numeric("x", domain = c(NA, NA), clamp = TRUE, nice = TRUE) %>%
  scale_numeric("y", domain = c(NA, NA), clamp = TRUE, nice = TRUE) %>%
  add_axis("x", title = "I don't know how this make this dynamic.") %>%
  layer_points()
```

(Unfortuntaly I could not figure out how to adjust the xlabel dynamically. If anyone knows, complementing would be very welcome.)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39666748/ggvis-using-a-variable-to-assign-x-property-using-props) from Jonathan H helped a lot!